# Getting the tick position and labels for Solid Guage using highcharts

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, highcharts

I am trying to build a guage using Highcharts.

The part I am unable to achieve is for the needle to touch the pink outer arc.
To change the font size of the number 8(It should display 8% in a larger font), to print 100% at the right end of the arc and to display some text at the center of the guage.

I tried my best to fix these issues but no luck.
I appreciate any advice on how to move forward.
Thanks in advance!

http://jsfiddle.net/q5hgky25/1/

```
<script src="http://code.highcharts.com/highcharts.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.highcharts.com/highcharts-more.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.highcharts.com/modules/solid-gauge.src.js"></script>
<div id="business-metrics-guage"></div>

$(function() {
    $('#business-metrics-guage').highcharts({
        chart: {
            type: 'solidgauge',
            spacingTop: 0,
            spacingRight: 0,
            spacingBottom: 0,
            spacingLeft: 0,
            plotBorderWidth: 0,
            marginRight: 0,
            marginLeft: 0,
            marginTop: 0,
            marginBottom: 0,
            backgroundColor: 'none'
        },
        tooltip: {
            enabled: false
        },
        title: {
            text: 'Test'
        },
        credits: {
            enabled: false
        },
        pane: {
            size: '140%',
            startAngle: -90,
            endAngle: 90,
            background: {
                innerRadius: '42%',
                outerRadius: '41%',
                backgroundColor: '#000',
                shape: 'arc'
            }
        },
        plotOptions: {
            solidgauge: {
                dataLabels: {
                    enabled: false
                }
            }
        },
        yAxis: {
            labels: {
                enabled: true,
                x: 10,
                y: -10
            },
            //tickPositions: [80, 90],           
            min: 0,
                max: 50,
                gridLineColor: 'transparent',
                lineColor: 'transparent',
                minorTickLength: 0,
                tickInterval: 67,
                tickPositions: [8], //8%
                tickColor: '#000000',
                tickPosition: 'inside',
                tickLength: 50,
                tickWidth: 2
            },
            series: [{
                data: [{
                    y: 8,
                    color: '#f95d6f'
                }], //y 8%
                dataLabels: [{
                    useHTML: true,
                    format: '<div style="text-align:center">Total here</div>'
                }],
                radius: '45%'
            }]
        });
    });
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all, there are four questions within your question and you should ask each one in a different question.

Any how, for the needle to touch the pink outer arc, you can use **`plotOptions.solidgauge.innerRadius`** and also change the size of the **`pane`** and it's background radius to fit your desired output:

```
plotOptions: {
    solidgauge: {
        innerRadius: '75%'
    }
}
```

For the font size of the label and it's **`%`** postfix, use **`yAxis.labels.format`** and **`style.fontSize`**:

```
yAxis: {
    labels: {
        enabled: true,
        x: 10, y: -10,
        format: '{value} %',
        style: {
            fontSize: 16
        }
    }
}
```

For displaying **`100 %`** at the right end, add **100** to `tickPositions` of yAxis:

```
tickPositions: [8, 100]
```

For some text in the center, you can use **`subtitle`**:

```
subtitle: {
    text: 'Total here'
}
```

Here's the [**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/q5hgky25/3/).